# Cross all edges of dodecahedron

Tags: geometry

Given a dodecahedron, find a path from a center of one of the faces through all 30 edges, crossing edges from face center to face center, only once. A face may be visited more than once.

Comment: Isn't this impossible? Youre asking us to find an euler path where a face is a vertex and the edges we cross are edges that connect vertices. Each face represents an odd vertex. If you start on one face, you should end outside of it. By the same token, if you start outside any face, you must finish on that face. Doesn't this require you to end on the 11 faces you didn't start with?

Comment: It seems it was way to easy... make it an answer and I will grant you the points. You are not required to end on a certain face - but the 7 bridges of Euler is the one...

Comment: I was just giving a really colloquial description, as in if you were to start outside of an odd vertex, an euler path would require you to finish your traversal there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question asks us to find an Eulerian Path along a graph - a Path that traverses each edge in the graph once and only once. The graph in this case has it's vertices represented by The faces, and the edges connecting the vertices are the edges (or the lines from center to center across an edge). If any graph has more than two odd vertices (i.e vertices with an odd number of edges connected to it), there is no Euler path for that graph. [More on Eulerian Paths.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_path)

Since a regular dodecahedron has 12 pentagonal faces, our graph has 12 odd vertices, and no Eulerian Path.